# How to cast a Map based on the type of its keys?

Tags: scala

I have a function, `getMap`, that returns `Map[Any, Double]`, to reflect that the type of the keys can vary.

However, the keys of each `Map` returned will all be of the same type, depending deterministically on the input, for example:

```
val intMap = getMap(someParam)

// the keys of intMap are all of type Int

val stringMap = getMap(someOtherParam)

// the keys of stringMap are all of type String
```

I would like to downcast each `Map` at runtime.

This is what I tried:

```
val actuallyIntMap = Map[Any, Double](1 -> 1.0)
type keyType = actuallyIntMap.head._1.getClass

val intMap = actuallyIntMap.asInstanceOf[Map[keyType, Double]]

// I expect intMap to be a Map[Int, Double]
```

The result is the following error:

```
error: stable identifier required, but this.intMap.head._1 found.
       type keyType = intMap.head._1.getClass
```

I suppose it's because `keyType` cannot be resolved at compile time...? While I could pattern match on the first value and create a `Map` that way, that seems like poor design (and tedious besides).

Is there any way to do this in Scala, assuming I cannot change the `getMap` function?

Comment: Do you own code of `getMap`? It would be probably easier to fix that function.

Comment: Your approach wouldn't work because `asIntanceOf` needs to know type on compile time and `head` wouldn't be known until runtime.

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik I guess that's to be expected. No, I can't modify `getMap`. Is this possible in a clean way at all in Scala?

Comment: @gmds as an alternative, if you can't modify `getMap`, you can just create a wrapper around it. And transform it to `val intMap = getMap[Int](param)`  for example for each call. Ofcourse deriving this type from parameter would be even better if your parameter contains type information.

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko But that still raises the question of how I would programmatically extract the type information without an exhaustive and manually implemented `match` statement or something like that. What I'm looking for is something like `type` in Python, where you can do something like `type(2)(5)` to get the `type` of `2`, which is `int`, and apply it to `5` as a constructor.

Comment: @gmds there is no way to `programmatically extract the type information` as there is no type available when you are trying to extract it. You can extract only class information as you did using `.getClass` but it's too late (runtime) to create a type based on it.

Comment: @gmds btw if you need something like Python"s `type` you can use `val cls: Class[_] = actuallyIntMap.head._1.getClass;println(cls.getName)` . But it's still runtime class but not a type.

Answer (score 1):

Your supposition is correct; this does not work because the type of `intMap` is not known at compile time.

If the result type is known at compile time, you can do something like this:

```
actuallyIntMap.collect{ case (i: Int, v) => i -> v }
```

This will return `Map[Int, Double]` and discard any entries where the key is not `Int`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, this doesn't really help me, because the result type definitely won't be known at compile time, and, for example, in a case where the `Map` can be converted to `Map[Int, Double]`, there will be no entries where the keys are *not `Int`.

Comment: What do you want to do with this new `Map` that you can't do with the original?

Comment: I want to turn it into a Spark DataFrame.

Comment: It would be useful to say this in the question. I am not familiar with Spark but there are probably ways of doing this directly without going through an intermediate value.